# Cache and Couchbase

Tags: caching, couchbase

I have a web application. The authentication tokens are stored in in-memory cache and not stored in database. I am using Couchbase for caching. During deployment of application, the cache will be lost and all the users will be logged out subsequently as tokens are stored in cache. What can I do to prevent my cache from being lost? I still don't want to use database for storing tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. The cache persists. Even after rebooting the server. Strange but yes it does. May be, couchbase flows cache to disk on rebooting. Also, my use case involved Spring which rules out possibility of using "memcached" type bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Are you flushing your buckets intentionally? Or you mean you are using "memcached" type of buckets which do not survive reboot?

I would recommend you to setup "couchbase" type of the bucket, and use expiration time when you are storing session. In this case you will have persistent session, but still not run out of space, because of old inactive sessions will be removed automatically.

Comment: I was using couchbase type of buckets. Spring cache doesn't support memcache type buckets. But the expiration time in ttl is not working fine for me. I mam setting the expiration time using the java sdk for spring cache.